# How to read objects and store into array

Tags: arrays, json, angular

I made an http request and got back e.g the below json. I want to read the cars and the shoes objects into separate arrays at the time of the http request.

**json**

```
{
 "id": 9, 
 "name": "Zlatan", 
 "cars": [
    {
     "type": "ford", 
     "year": "2019"
    },
    {
     "type": "audi", 
     "year": "2017"
    }
  ]
 "shoes": [
    {
     "brand": "adidas", 
     "status": "old"
    },
    {
     "brand": "timberland", 
     "status": "new"
    }
  ]
}
```

**comp.ts**

```
cars = [];
shoes = [];
//......

getZlatan() {
   return this.httpService.getInfo()
         .subscribe( data => {
                this.objZlatan = data;   //this part holds the json obj above
                this.cars ....//what to add here
                this.shoes ....// here too. 
            } );
}
```

Or is there a cleaner way to load the arrays at http request?

Comment: this.cars = data.cars; this.shoes  =  data.shoes. Doesn't this work?

Comment: `this.cars = data.cars`, `this.shoes = data.shoes`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `.` and type names to access `cars` and `shoes`. Let me show an example:

```
return this.httpService.getInfo()
     .subscribe( data => {
            this.objZlatan = data;   //this part holds the json obj above
            this.cars = data.cars;
            this.shoes =data.shoes;
        } );
```

Answer (score 1):

Access the `cars` and `shoes` properties of the data with simple dot-notation. It might be ideal to check if the data returned is not null with `if(condition here)` and then perform your logic. If you have more objects and want to bring all cars and shoes under one array then you have to loop through.

```
getZlatan() {
    return this.httpService.getInfo()
        .subscribe(data => {
            this.objZlatan = data;
            this.cars = this.objZlatan.cars;
            this.shoes = this.objZlatan.shoes; 
        });
}
```